# How to view data from mySql in a bootstrap table?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

Actually i've started to use VB.NET and ASPX and i would add data from my DB in my bootstrap table, actually here is the code of a static table, where the values of the <'td'> should be taken from the database and created <'tr'> for each item from the db.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card strpied-tabled-with-hover">
                        <div class="card-header ">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Realco App</h4>
                            <p class="card-category">Qui sono presentit tutte le versioni dell'App Realco</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body table-full-width table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Software</th>
                                    <th>Versione</th>
                                    <th>Release Data</th>
                                    <th>Download</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>App2</td>
                                        <td>0.9.0</td>
                                        <td>02/01/2019</td>
                                        <td><a href="#" aria-disabled="true"  data-version="App2.apk">Download</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>App</td>
                                        <td>0.2.3</td>
                                        <td>02/01/2019</td>
                                        <td><a href="#" aria-disabled="true" data-version="App.apk">Download</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

While here is the VB.NET part where i connect to the DB and taking the data from clienti_sw table, but now i need some suggestion on how to add that data to the table..

```
   Dim SQLConnect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clienti_sw"



    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in-line

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim SQLConnect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString
    'This is where you collect the downloaded data
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'The using block insures that your database objects are closed and disposed releasing any
    'unmanaged resources
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        'You can pass the command text and the connection to the constructor
        'of the command
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clienti_sw", con)
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    'In a WinForms app the datatable can be bound
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'Not sure how this is done in asp
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```